# Is it possible to add a Movieclip in a specific frame?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, frame, movieclip, addchild

I add a menu button in the first frame (from an external class).
When i click it, it goes to the second frame, and it's still there.

Is it possible to add a mc in a specific frame?
I try to remove it while clicking on it but it gives me error...

Thanks!

Comment: I've tried doing:

    addFrameScript(1, onFrame1);

  private function onFrame1():void 
  {
   addButtons();
  }

But it won't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove your button by clicking like that :

```
function clicBouton(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(2);
    e.target.parent.removeChild(e.target);
}
```

Comment: @Johny - This thread should rather be renamed : "How to remove a button by clicking it?"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the addFrameScript() function to do so, as you already seem to have found out.

Here an example:

http://www.flashwork.biz/blog/?p=229

To tell you what you exact problem is you most likely need to post more details, but looking at your comment, you might have simply missed that addFrameScript() frame numbers start with 0 (zero) while frames in the IDE start at 1. Substract 1 from the frame number that the IDE shows.

An example:

If you want to add a script for frame 1 you should use

addFrameScript(0, onFrame1);